Migration from SimpleSAMLPhP 1x to 2.x
I have a very old instance of SimpleSAMLPHP that I am trying to migrate the configuration files from the older v1.x to the newer v2.x styles.
In my saml20-sp-remote.php, I have the metadata for one of my remote sp's
$metadata['xxx'] = [
    'AssertionConsumerService' => 'https://mydomain.test/SAML/AssertionConsumerService',
    'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
    'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'username',
    'simplesaml.attributes' => false,
];

from what I understand simplesaml.nameidattribute doesn't work anymore and needs to be migrated to the authproc filters but I'm unsure how to do this (is there anything else here that will not work?)
